# Peer testing - Any good references?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, integration-testing

Recently I was assigned a story for performing Peer testing of changes carried out by my teammate. I am confused because he has already written his own test cases for unit testing the code. Then why am I required to do the same code's testing?
I am also a developer not a QA.
I have questions like 
    Am I suppose to cross verify the test cases ? 
    what is the goal of Peer testing? how to do it?

Are there any good references or articles on the same ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26058/peer-review-for-tests-just-like-code-reviews/27090#27090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with David Whiteman that between the other dev's tests and your own, each will likely cover the other's blind spots. However, it's not just about code coverage, it's also about test design.

My experience of unit testing in two recent "intro to programming" type courses indicates that even the overlapping tests can have value--**when writing tests against your own code it can be harder to decouple testing results from testing implementation**. One course actually *encouraged* writing the implementation into the tests, and when that changed, cascading failures would occur even if the behavior was correct.

To clarify what I mean, the common phrasing is ["test the interface, not the implementation."](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/test-the-interface-not-the-implementation) When designing tests for your code, you should *rely only on the contracts of the interface* the code *should* provide to other classes. For instance, a test that accesses member variables of the object it's testing should use getters and setters, or do without, because the variables might be renamed or even removed. If the member variable in question is an object, it might even change types, never mind change the types of its member variables.

Consider writing tests against the following class, which for simplicity happens to be a HomemadeStack.

```
public class HomemadeStack {
    private Object[] theStack;
    @postcondition: stack is not empty, and contains one more element
    public void push(Object o) {
        // implementation specific to an array
    }
    @precondition: stack is not empty
    @postcondition stack contains one less element
    public Object pop() throws StackUnderflowException {
        // implementation specific to an array
    }
    @postcondition: the stack is empty (isEmpty() will return true)
    public void clear() {
        // again, implementation specific to an array
    }
    @returns: true only if there are no objects on the stack
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // again, implementation specific to an array
    }
}
```

If you're having to change access modifiers to execute the test, at least in my experience, it's a good sign you're testing wrong. The variable theStack in HomemadeStack *should* be private. The course mentioned earlier had us write tests like the following, where testStack in a non-empty instance of HomemadeStack:

```
void testClearMethodResultsInEmptyStack {
    testStack.clear();
    assert testStack.theStack.size()==0;
}
```

This test assumes too much about the implementation. It would also require the dev to give theStack looser access modifiers to test from a external class. However, it's very easy to write a test like this, then write the clear method to meet the test. It passes, so is it a problem? Well, to list a few implementation assumptions inherent in the above test:

1. that a variable called theStack exists in HomemadeStack
2. whatever type of variable theStack is, it is an object with a size() method
3. most importantly, that the underlaying data structure of a "cleared" stack has size 0, rather than the same size it had before it was cleared, except with a "first available" pointer updated, or some other approach.

Now, suppose you're told to convert HomemadeStack to use a linked list internally, and name the variable "theList." Even if the new implementation pushed, popped, cleared, and checked emptiness (that is, implemented the contracts of the interface) correctly, none of the implementation assumptions that went into the tests would survive! So now you've written a working class with failing tests, but nobody can say where the problem is yet. How many hours of consternation and additional work would ensue?

To test the interface without those extra assumptions, I was taught in the other course to rely on the contracts of isEmpty() and clear():

```
void testClearMethodResultsInEmptyStack {
    testStack.clear();
    assert testStack.isEmpty();
}
```

One would also rely on clear() to test that pop() throws StackUnderFlowException when its contract is broken, etc. That's testing to the interface, and it's more robust. If you're "a step back" from the code being tested, it's easier to write tests that "take a step back" too.

As an afterthought, the more I reflect on it, the more I believe that the programming course which taught me to approach test-driven development the "wrong way around" was attempting to teach students the hard way about why best practices exist, and to get a very bad feeling when slipping into less-than-ideal practices, before things break. The other course taught TDD how many would consider "the right way around," but left us students with no first-hand experience of why it's best.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a small example as to what do you mean by 'writing implementation into tests'? And is it applicable only when testing my own code ?

Comment: @DolphinJava it's tempting to write implementation into tests any time you're white-box testing. Avoid it while writing your peer tests, too. Hopefully my edit brings more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to help catch areas where the developer's unit tests were incomplete.  As developers, we all have our blind spots when it comes to writing unit tests or running ad-hoc tests.